# Link comparison operators the way it works on algebra

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning python, in specific comparison operators. Let say I want to check if a number is between two values.

In math, let say X is a number, this can be expressed as: 70 < x < 80

I know that in python this can be written as:

```
x = number
if (x>70) and (x<80):
    pass
```

I check in the interpreter if it's possible to write instead:

```
x = number
if(70<x<80):
    pass
```

And effective it does work. My doubt is, is this syntax correct? Can I get a problem because write the code in this way?

Sorry if the question is to newbie but I need to be sure that my code will work and I can not find information on internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `if 70<x<80:` syntax is legal in Python and does what you want it to do.  In most other common programming languages it is either illegal or has a very unintuitive meaning, so be careful as you start experimenting with other languages.

In Python, you can extend this even farther, so `if a < b < c < d:` is legal, for example.

Here's the Python reference manual section on comparison expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons.

By the way, there is no need in Python to put parentheses around each comparison, but you can certainly do so if it helps you read your own code.

Comment: It's legal in `C` and `C++` and probably others, but it doesn't mean what the naive programmer might think it means! It's like (in Python) `if 70 < x: 1 < 80; else: 0 < 80`

Comment: Good point about C and C++, where it is legal but a really bad idea!

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is perfectly legal (and guaranteed) behavior.  There are called ["chained comparisons"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are
>   comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to
>   a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.
>
> Note that a op1 b op2 c doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between a
>   and c, so that, e.g., x < y > z is perfectly legal (though perhaps not
>   pretty).

Here's how it works:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f(x):
       return 70 < x < 80

>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (70)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (80)
             14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Interestingly, the tests are separate and not dependent on one another, so you can write:

```
>>> x = 20
>>> 40 > x < 30
True
```

That means `40 > x and x < 30`.